# What is the reference number needed for the Tax Info in iTunes Connect?

Tags: app-store-connect

I look at the instructions but there's nothing there. As if it was obvious but I'm really clueless.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this a question for Apple Developer Relations.

Comment: I'm clearing the close votes. Apple Developer relations is a service Apple offers and all Apple Services are on topic per [help]. If we want to change this scope - [meta] is the place to organize a change to scope for the site.

Comment: @Mark See above. This isn't close worthy just because it's for the tunes-connect. (not all iTunes connect questions will be good - but this one is, too)

Comment: @bmike Maybe I should have flagged it for Stack Overflow. In either case I  didn't think that it was likely to get a very good answer here. Thanks for your input. I appreciate the guidance.

Comment: Cheers  @Mark . I can totally see your intent to help. In reality, SO is migrating questions like this here for answers now.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions state if you're a foreign individual who is the single owner of a disregarded entity that is not claiming treaty benefits as a hybrid entity, with respect to a payment, and the account to which a payment is made or credited is in the name of the disregarded entity, you should write the name and account number of the disregarded entity on line 7 "Reference number" in order to inform the withholding agent of this fact.

Comment: Still confused... Can I leave this blank since Im just an individual with no disregarded entities?

Comment: Yes, in that case you can leave it blank.